# MySQL - How to find rows based on value in previous row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a  setting table:

```
create table settings(
    id int
  , date datetime
  , user varchar(20)
  , status varchar(10)
  );

insert into settings values
 (1 , '2020-07-10 14:36:06', 'user1', 'INACTIVE'),
 (1 , '2020-07-10 14:39:54', 'user1', 'ACTIVE'),
 (1 , '2020-07-10 14:44:06', 'user1', 'INACTIVE'),
 (1 , '2020-07-10 14:46:06', 'user2', 'INACTIVE'),
 (1 , '2020-07-10 14:49:06', 'user2', 'SCHEDULED'),
 (1 , '2020-07-10 14:55:06', 'user2', 'ACTIVE'),
 (2 , '2020-07-12 14:36:06', 'user1', 'INACTIVE'),
 (2 , '2020-07-13 14:39:54', 'user1', 'INACTIVE'),
 (2 , '2020-07-13 16:44:06', 'user1', 'ACTIVE'),
 (2 , '2020-07-15 14:46:06', 'user3', 'INACTIVE'),
 (2 , '2020-07-15 15:49:06', 'user3', 'INACTIVE'),
 (2 , '2020-07-17 14:46:06', 'user3', 'ACTIVE')
 ;
```

example code with insert code is in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84789e/3)

The process starts from `INACTIVE` status and it is scheduled by system then user could change to `SCHEDULED` or `ACTIVE`.

I need to find rows which have `ACTIVE` status but only these one which before is row with `INACTIVE` status grouped by user. Specific case (not sure if it is possible) to find rows with `ACTIVE` status but if previous rows have `SCHEDULED -> INACTIVE`  sequence.

I selected on the below screenshot which rows should be returned:

[image]

I was trying with it but the result should return previous row under current row.

```
select * from (  
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 row, a.* 
from settings a
where a.status = 'ACTIVE'
) as cr

LEFT JOIN (SELECT  @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 row, b.* FROM settings b
where b.status = 'INACTIVE' ) as pr
on cr.id = pr.id and cr.date > pr.date
```

Comment: This will help you https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-if-else/

Comment: `select * from settings where status = 'ACTIVE'` you can find by this. if you consider active is after inactive there nothing unique, so it means only active!

Comment: @BloodyLogic Sqlserver is not the same as mysql and code written in one will not necessarily transfer to the other.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1):

You could use self-join to do this.
After doing self-join, from one table (say A) get ACTIVE time for each date and from another table (say B) get Inactive time where `B.date<A.date`.

Then you can perform other operation on both date like getting time duration or something.

Check fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84789e/23

Query :

```
SELECT A.user,max(B.date) as Inactive,min(A.date) as Active 
FROM settings A JOIN settings B
ON A.id=B.id and A.user=B.user
WHERE A.status = 'ACTIVE'
AND B.status = 'INACTIVE'
AND B.date<A.date
GROUP BY  A.date,A.user
```

Comment: @Strawberry can you provide an edge case so that i can look into it with detail

Comment: Sorry - I meant id.

Comment: @Strawberry please post a sqlfiddle and also missing values that is expected in the result.

Comment: It's the first column in the OP's picture above, that's all. We can assume that the result should contain the following columns (id, date, user, status)

Comment: @Strawberry that column is some foreign key from what i presumed and it is not required in the output. If OP wants that column, it will be just adding that in select list and in group by. I didn't felt it is necessary in the output.

Comment: @Strawberry: that's true when in comes of the list of the following columns (id, date, user, status).

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r It didn't solve my problem. The result should be presented as on the screenshot from the original message and with the marked rows. It is mainly about this rule where the "Active" status follows "Inactive".